# R - lmer drops unused levels in a random effect

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, lmer

I am calling the `lFormula` function in `lmer` (`lme4` 1.1-9) to get the transpose of the sparse model matrix of a random effect (`Zt`). The problem is that unused levels are dropped in the output matrix. Is-there a way to get around this?

I realize that this question might seem awkward, so [here](https://gist.github.com/nrode/71722932408071ea4f62) is an example on GitHub Gist trying to fit a multiple-membership model with a factor that has more levels than observations.

Comment: Any chance of a [reproducible example](http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000) ?

Comment: Thanks Ben, I edited the question to go straight to the point and now provide a reproducible example using a multiple-merbership model.